# confirmation on button not working

Tags: html, validation, button, user-controls

for some reason, my confirmation function is not working. here is the code:

```
<tr>
                <td align ="right" style ="Width: 50%;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Confirm Order" 
                        onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="confirm();" />

                        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
                            function confirm() {
                                if (Page_ClientValidate())
                                    return confirm('Confirm Order?');
                            }
                </script>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td align ="left" style ="Width: 50%;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel Order" 
                        onclick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="cancel();" />

                        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
                            function cancel() {
                                if (Page_ClientValidate())
                                    return confirm('Cancel Order?');
                            }
                 </script>
```

Obviously what i want to happen is to have a confirmation when the client clicks on the button. However this line of codes is perfectly fine in my other pages. However, its not working since i am calling this function inside a user control, does it have anything to do with it?

thank you for any help/tricks.

Comment: You don't have to create the validate function twice, and i believe you can call the function without the "return" before it.

Comment: Its been a while since I looked at ASP, but i would suggest that you have two instances of the same function name and it would be better to have separate names for each. or a single function that can handle each response independantly

Comment: i have considered both of your comments. already edited my question above. still unlucky to make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

There should no return at OnClientClick="return validate();" it should be OnClientClick="validate()"
see the code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396